# Use PyCharm to debug a python while executing code in jupyter notebook

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook, conda

So here's my scenario:

1. I am in a conda environment, and now using a browser to debug a python script using jupyter notebook.
2. These scripts import some python library.
3. Using PyCharm to examine the code as I run the scripts.
4. As I execute a jupyter notebook cell, I'd like PyCharm to stop at a breakpoint in the original library.

I wonder if this could be done. Coming from a Java server programming world, I know that JEE exposes certain APIs that allow one to remotely debug a Java application. This would be immensely helpful for python also, i suppose.

Comment: Have you looked at [this documentation from Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging.html)?

Comment: I have the same question.  I have looked at the Jetbrains documentation suggested by NonCreature0714 and didn't find the solution.  If I have missed something please tell me what I should be looking for.  An interesting thing is that I have inadvertently been able to get it to work, but don't know what triggered it.  I have never gotten it to work except by accident.